# Restrict access to resources by resource ID in CakePHP using ACL

Tags: cakephp, acl, access-control

Let's say I have a `Project` model and a `User` model in a CakePHP application. Using ACL I can control if users can access to projects and/or to particular actions in a `ProjectsController`.

But I would like to go further and control whether a user is allowed to view a specific project, e.g. accessing a project with `id = 3` using a URL like http://example.com/projects/3.

Is this possible with ACL as well or I have to develop additional checks on top of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restrict access to specific values of a model, you'll need to use something other than ACL.

It'll be best to define a relationship between the users and projects, whether that's inclusive or exclusive.

You're probably needing a ProjectUser model (HABTM in Project and User) and a simple function in that model, maybe `userAllowed($projectId, $userId)`, that checks that the user has been given access to that project.